# PHP: check from which page the link is directed

Tags: php

lets say i have a page `hit.php` in my website and the link is to this page is available on every\many pages in the website..

lets say i click `<a href"hit.php">HIT</a>` from any page.....

is there a way when `hit.php` is loaded i could know that the page from which this page was..

meaning if i click the link to `hit.php` from 'index.php' i could check loading `hit.php` that the user is navigating here from 'index.php' or any other page...

i know this i could establish in site by passing variables in URL like 'hit.php?pagename=index' but is there another way

p.s i know its crazy but still :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, although it can easily be spoofed or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the referer.  In PHP, it's:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

However, users can configure their browsers not to send this, or spoof it.  You should ensure that your code doesn't break if it's absent, or faked.

Comment: @Junaid, I meant you should take care to ensure that it doesn't break.